# Function definition: fun vs val

Tags: kotlin

I'm curious about what is the suggested way to define member functions in Kotlin. Consider these two member functions:

```
class A {

  fun f(x: Int) = 42

  val g = fun(x: Int) = 42

}
```

These appear to accomplish the same thing, but I found subtle differences.

The `val` based definition, for instance, seems to be more flexible in some scenarios. That is, I could not work out a straight forward way to compose `f` with other functions, but I could with `g`. To toy around with these definitions, I used the [funKTionale](https://github.com/MarioAriasC/funKTionale) library. I found that this does not compile:

```
val z = g andThen A::f // f is a member function
```

But if `f` were defined as a `val` pointing to the same function, it would compile just fine. To figure out what was going on I asked IntelliJ to explicitly define the type of `::f` and `g` for me, and it gives me this:

```
val fref: KFunction1<Int, Int> = ::f

val gref: (Int) -> Int = g
```

So one is of type `KFunction1<Int, Int>`, the other is of type `(Int) -> Int`. It's easy to see that both represent functions of type `Int -> Int`.

What is the difference between these two types, and in which cases does it matter? I noticed that for top-level functions, I can compose them fine using either definition, but in order to make the aforementioned composition compile, I had to write it like so:

```
val z = g andThen A::f.partially1(this)
```

i.e. I had to partially apply it to `this` first.

Since I don't have to go through this hassle when using `val`s for functions, is there a reason why I should ever define non-Unit member functions using `fun`? Is there a difference in performance or semantics that I am missing?

Comment: one huge thing about vals is the lack of parametricity, this does not compile: `val id = fun<T>(t:T) = t`

Comment: Ah good point! Hadn't thought about that. Definitely something to consider.

Comment: Does g have access to instance properties?

Comment: @JacobZimmerman it does, although indeed not apparent from my example. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 40):

Kotlin is all about Java interoperability and defining a function as a `val` will produce a completely different result in terms of the interoperability. The following Kotlin class:

```
class A {
  fun f(x: Int) = 42
  val g = fun(x: Int) = 42
}
```

is effectively equivalent to:

```
public class A {
  private final Function1<Integer, Integer> gref = new Function1<Integer, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer invoke(final Integer integer) {
      return 42;
    }
  };

  public int f(final int value) {
    return 42;
  }

  public Function1<Integer, Integer> getG() {
    return gref;
  }
}
```

As you can see, the main differences are:

1. `fun f` is just a usual method, while `val g` in fact is a higher-order function that returns another function
2. `val g` involves creation of a new class which isn't good if you are targeting Android
3. `val g` requires unnecessary boxing and unboxing
4. `val g` cannot be easily invoked from java: `A().g(42)` in Kotlin vs `new A().getG().invoke(42)` in Java

**UPDATE:**

Regarding the `A::f` syntax. The compiler will generate an extra `Function2<A, Integer, Integer>` class for **every** `A::f` occurrence, so the following code results in two extra classes with **7 methods** each:

```
val first = A::f
val second = A::f
```

Kotlin compiler isn't smart enough at the moment to optimize such kind of things. You can vote for the issue here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-9831. In case you are interested, here is how each class looks in the bytecode: https://gist.github.com/nsk-mironov/fc13f2075bfa05d8a3c3

Comment: Ah great, this is exactly the kind of information I was looking for. Follow up question: would "reifying" `f` using `::f` result in Kotlin creating an internal function class similarly to what you describe here is done for `g`?

Comment: Basicly yes. Only when you use `inline` function, the class generation may be skipped.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some code showing how f and g are different when it comes to usage:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a = A()
    exe(a.g)  // OK
    //exe(a.f)  // does not compile
    exe { a.f(it) }  // OK
}

fun exe(p: (Int) -> Int) {
    println(p(0))
}
```

Where `f` and `g` are:

```
  fun f(x: Int) = 42

  val g = fun(x: Int) = 42
```

You can see that g is an object that can be used like a lambda, but f cannot.  To use f similarly, you have to wrap it in a lambda.

Comment: Could you add the `f` and `g` function definitions so we have more context when reading your answer?

Comment: f and g are defined in the question.

Comment: Yeah, but copying them would help readability and save some mouse wheels, especially since there's other answers between the question and your answer

Comment: Is this not just because the syntax is different? `a.g` is a reference to a fun; `a.f` is not; you should use method reference syntax: `a::f`. Having just tested this, `exe(a::f)` does indeed work!