# Implementing an interface with parametrized function

Tags: kotlin

Suppose I have an interface

```
interface A {
    fun  calculate(n: Int): Int
}
```

I'd like to implement `A` in a class `B` (say) so that the `calculation` is provided in `B`'s  constructor, something like:

```
class B (f : (Int) -> Int) : A {
    override fun  calculate(n: Int): Int  //...somehow assign f to calculate
}
```

Can this be done without making `f` a property of `B`?

Hmm... this works:

```
interface A {
    val calculate: (n: Int) -> Int
}

class B(f: (Int) -> Int) : A {
    override val calculate = f
}
```

Can someone explain the intended syntactic difference between `fun` and `val` here? I am aware of [Function definition: fun vs val](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36118235/function-definition-fun-vs-val) but would like to get a 'language level' understanding.

Comment: Why is it a problem to make f a property of B? You can make it private, if that's your concern.

Comment: Yes , I can do `(private val f : (Int) -> Int)` and then have `calculate(n: Int): Int  = f(n)` but this feels clunky to me.

Comment: Well, you need to store a reference to the function somewhere, and that's what properties are for.

Comment: Any chance of `calculate` be that reference ?

Comment: As far as I know, no. You can create an anonymous class instance where calculate() call f, and the reference to f would then be stored as a synthetic field (not sure if it's the proper terminology), and not as a property. But that wouldn't change much.

Comment: Regarding your second question, if you had do use it in Java, instead of doing `int i = a.calculate(42)`, you would have to do `int i = a.getCalculate().invoke(42);`. You don't have a method anymore. You have a property of type function.

Comment: But in Kotlin we will end up calling `b.calculate(1)` regardless of `fun/var`. When compiling to JS will be completed we will be able to demonstrate the difference in JS too. I am trying to understand the intent in Kotlin terms.

Comment: Well, the intent of the first one is to Add a method calculate to the interface, whereas the intent of the second one is to add a property of type function. It's quite different. If it was a var rather than a val, you could for example reassign another function to calculate.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to implement this is:

```
class B(val f : (Int) -> Int) : A {
    override fun calculate(n: Int): Int = f(n)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done without making `f` a property of `B`. e.g. By using [class delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html#class-delegation) to an [object expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions):

```
class B(f: (Int) -> Int) : A by object : A {
    override fun calculate(n: Int) = f(n)
}
```

Even so, a `private val` seems more appropriate for this simple example.

Comment: This actually is a double delegation, isn't it? The anonymous class instance delegates to f, and the class B delegates to the anonymous class instance.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes: implementation of an interface is delegated and implementation of a function is delegated so in that sense it certainly is. Thanks for pointing that out!